# What is the size of the cache memory on Mac?

Tags: macos, caching, memory

I have a Mac laptop and I would like to know what the size of my cache memory is. When I check the properties of my hardware I can only see 
the sizes of the L2 and L3 caches, but not the L1. Does anybody know a way to get this information?

Thanks

PS: I am not very familiar with computer architecture.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On a Mac, you can ask sysctl:

```
$ sysctl hw.l1icachesize   # L1 instruction cache
hw.l1icachesize: 32768

$ sysctl hw.l1dcachesize   # L1 data cache
hw.l1dcachesize: 32768
```

Or you can look it up in the [Intel specs](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf). Search for Table 2-9 (Cache Parameters of the Haswell Microarchitecture).

I don't know why System Profiler doesn't spit it out, other than 32k (per core) is really common for all the modern CPUs I know, so maybe so consistent over the product line that it's not worth reporting.